# What is happening with inclusive OR during a shift when combining bits

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, cpu-registers

I  know this is a beginner question: This may be something I do not understand with computer architecture or registers, but what is happening when you bit shift and then use the | (inclusive OR) operator? I understand that using OR can turn on bits;

but the following gets a 'bit' confusing for me; for example I have seen code that converts Big endian data to Little endian by

```
int value = (buffer[i++] << 24) | (buffer[i++] << 16)
          | (buffer[i++] << 8) | buffer[i++];
```

And in my own code I have converted byte streams by doing:

```
short a = (short)(buffter[0] | (buffer[1] << 8));
```

But these ORs do not make sense to me, isn't OR used to turn on bits?

```
       0101
       1100
Result:1101
```

If I was actually using OR in the way I understand it, then if byte[i] = 2 and byte[i+1] =3, then

0010 | 0011 = 0011 = 3.

Is the shift making the data in the byte overflow to some wider spot in memory before doing the inclusive OR? i.e. 
`0010 | 0011 << 4` equivalent to `00000010 | 00110000`?
If this is the case, then how big is too big of a shift since you can't pad 0s forever?

Comment: Pick a language: bit shifting has all sorts of edge-conditions and language dependencies.

Comment: This is C#, but I'm interested in all c languages. I'll adjust edit my question.

Comment: Probably related, because I do not trust those multiple `i++` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: You don't have `0010 | 0011`.  The shift is extending the value so you have something like `0010 | 00110000`

Comment: Your code is undefined in C and C++, so best to remove the tags.

Comment: C++ development was begun on top of C. C# development was surely strongly inspired by C++. However, all these languages are developed independently though there might be influences to each other. So, I wouldn't dare to say something like "all C languages" - as you have seen the community is very critical about this. :-)

Comment: @Scheff gotcha. I would have though bit shifting would behave similarly but I guess I'll have to learn the other languages another time

Comment: @Goku; they almost do but the far worse problem is that in C and C++, your multiple i++ between non-sequenced steps puts your entire program into an undefined state.

Comment: @Bathsheba wow. would that mean I would have to store the result of each shift in a new line of code before going to the next?

Comment: @Goku, nah, you just use i, i + 1, i  + 2, i + 3, then i +=4 as a separate statement. And that's probably better anyway as it's arguably more parallelisable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of how bitwise OR works is correct.  If either corresponding bit is set then the resulting bit is set.

When you perform a shift however those bits move.  So the binary value `0011` shifted left 4 bits gives you `00110000`.  If you then OR that with `0010` you get:

```
  00000010
| 00110000
  --------
  00110010
```

As far as how big a shift is too big, that depends entirely on the type.

Comment: by type do you mean the type I'm storing in? i.e. int 32 should not have more than 32 bits total or a shift of a byte by 24 bits?

Comment: @Goku An `int` isn't guaranteed to be 32 bits.  It could be 16 bits.  You need to make sure it is the right size before you start fiddling with it.

Comment: @NathanOliver In C# it's guaranteed to be 32 bits. You're thinking of C/C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver by int32 I should have said 'Int32' (C# data type)

Comment: @itsme86 I just noticed that the tags were changed.  I still thought this was tagged as C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Right size and complementing scheme.